# Spammers/Bots bypassing Google Recaptcha V2 server side validation (PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter, recaptcha

I have a form setup with Codeigniter that is using Google Recaptcha V2, installed via composer "google/recaptcha": "^1.2"

```
$rules = array(
    array('field' => 'g-recaptcha-response', 'label' => 'ReCaptcha', 'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|required|callback_recaptcha_validation'),
);
```

I am using a callback that uses the following code to verify the recaptcha.

```
//recaptcha callback
public function recaptcha_validation($gRecaptchaResponse)
{           
    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($this->config->item('private_recaptcha_key'));
    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
        $error_string = '';
        $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
        if($errors && count($errors) > 0) {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                $error_string .= "<p>".$error."</p>";
            }
        }

        // $this->form_validation->set_message('recaptcha_validation', $error_string);

        //display human error
        $this->form_validation->set_message('recaptcha_validation', 'Your CAPTCHA response did not match. Please try again.');

        return FALSE;
    } 

    return TRUE;  
}
```

This all seems to work as intended, I have tested with Postman and when I omit the recaptcha field I get the required rule for g-recaptcha-response. When I submit g-recaptcha-response with some fake data, I get the callback error from the failed server side validation.

However this exact approach was not able to prevent a spammer/bot from hitting the form with a couple hundred fake submissions over the course of a few months.

Am I missing something, or is this approach just not good enough to protect against spammers in 2021? Perhaps I need to use V3 or some kind of honeypot library to protect against spammers. Looking for some advice on this issue, or perhaps there is something wrong with my setup that I am not seeing.

Comment: Bots have been using humans to bypass captchas for years. I won't post links but you can easily find such services and they are very cheap. Captchas will never be a complete solution, merely a deterrent.

Comment: A competent form validation (server side and client side) also frustrates spammers/bots, maybe even more than any captcha

Comment: The verify response also has a score (higher is better). You can block low scores but some will be legit traffic.